# Отправка файла с помощью Skype4com.dll

Tags: delphi, skype

Уважаемые, есть такие, кто работал с библиотекой `Skype4com.dll`? мне необходимо произвести отправку файла программно, но что-то не могу найти функцию. Премного благодарен за любую информацию.

Answer (score 1):

```
Skype1.Client.OpenFileTransferDialog('SkypeUserHandle', 'c:\StartPath');
```